# Reference Figures like "Fig. XX" instead "Figure XX"

Tags: graphics, hyperref, cross-referencing, labels

I tried to references my Figure like "Fig.1" but it referenced like "Figure 1" using \autoref.

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Images/Figure-1.png}
\caption{foo}\label{fig:Fig-1}
\end{figure}

Then the text:
bla bla {See \autoref{fig:Fig-1}}
```

I need to display the references like "Fig. 1" instead "Figure 1".
How can I solve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`hyperref` uses `\<type>autorefname` with `<type>` the thing you're referencing (for instance `equation`, or `figure`) to determine the name (if it exists, else it falls back to `\<type>name`). You can simply redefine that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand\figureautorefname{Fig.\@} % `\@` added for correct spacing

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-duck}
\caption{foo}\label{fig:Fig-1}
\end{figure}

Then the text:
bla bla {See \autoref{fig:Fig-1}}
\end{document}
```